# how to pass argument to const object variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants, let

Given

```
 onColumnResize(column) {

    const columnsWidth = {
        columnsWidth: {
            column: width + 'px'
        },
        detail: this.details
    };
```

}

how to pass argument column to the object columnsWidth variable?
for example: if argument column = 'name', would like to pass 'name' to column and output the following (depending on the argument of the function):

```
onColumnResize(column) {
 const columnsWidth = {
        columnsWidth: {
            'name': width + 'px'
        },
        detail: this.details
    };
}
```

my attempt:
`

```
 onColumnResize(column) {
      const columnsWidth = {};
      columnsWidth[column] = width+'px';
      columnsWidth.detail = this.details;
  }`
```

is there other method beside the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `column` to `[column]` in your first code block:

```
onColumnResize(column) {
  const columnsWidth = {
    columnsWidth: {
      [column]: width + 'px'
    },
    detail: this.details
  };

  // ...
}
```

This is called a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), and it's part of ES2015, not ES2016.

Comment: that saves my day. Thanks much !